# events/[event_id]/attendances in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I'm building an events application, and I want to be able to retrieve each event's attendances by hitting an endpoint structured as in the question title: `events/[event_id]/attendances`. How do I declare such a route in `routes.rb`?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the rails guide on nested routing:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks!